# While deploying a simple web application, the java file (i.e servlet) doesn't run on server (Tomcat)

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

[image: Error Message![][1]]
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ui6ba.png)There is no error in .java file and I have created the form.html. The tomcat is working fine, as when I try to run .html it runs fine but when I try to run the .java file it shows the error  "Servlet BeerSelect is not available" whereas I have defined it.
Sorry guys, I'm new here so don't have the require reputation to put the pictures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot simply run a .java file as it is on tomcat. It should be a servlet for that purpose.

An example of simple servlet is:

```
    package com.jenkov.butterfly;
    import java.io.IOException;

    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
        public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws IOException {
            response.getWriter().println("Hello");
        }
    }
```

If it is already a servlet, you might be missing the mapping in **web.xml**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.jenkov.butterfly.MyServlet</servlet-class>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/MyServlet</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Alternatively, you might add **@WebServlet** annotation:

```java
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/MyServlet")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException {
        response.getWriter().println("Hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: probably error is because of <servlet-class>BeerV1.BeerSelect</servlet-class> which should be <servlet-class>BeerSelect</servlet-class> , there is no package named BeerV1